# Open Location Services view programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, url-scheme

How to open "Location Services" view programmatically with schemes as do Apple Maps in iOS6?
I didn't find answer here: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefs:// scheme has been introduced with iOS 5.0 and removed with iOS 5.1.

You have to pop a message to your user and explain him how to got to enable the location services in the settings.